# Websocket client can't connect to the server on DigitalOcean app platform

Tags: javascript, socket.io, digital-ocean, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 application with socket.io running on DigitalOcean app platform where the client can't connect to the web socket server.

The web socket runs on the same port `3000` as the application, with:

- nuxt.config.js

```js
import startSocketServer from "./server/sockets"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  hooks: {
    listen: (nuxtServer) => startSocketServer(nuxtServer)
  },
  ...
});
```

- ./server/sockets/index.js

```js
import {  Server } from "socket.io";

export default (nuxtServer) => {
  const io = new Server(nuxtServer)
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`connection ${socket.id}`)
  });
};
```

And on the client I have:

```js
const socketDomain = (isLocal) ? 'localhost:3000' : 'my.domain.com'

const socket = io(socketDomain, {
  transports: ['websocket'],

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log('connect')
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err}`);
});
```

The application run perfectly locally with `nuxi dev` or `nuxi build && node .output/server/index.mjs` but when I deploy on DigitalOcean I get the following:

```bash
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: 
doOpen @ entry.3f5d167e.js:21
open @ entry.3f5d167e.js:20
open @ entry.3f5d167e.js:21
$i @ entry.3f5d167e.js:21
A1.exports @ entry.3f5d167e.js:21
open @ entry.3f5d167e.js:21
(anonymous) @ entry.3f5d167e.js:21
invoice.22658294.js:1 connect_error due to Error: websocket error
```

I also tried with the web socket on a different port, but from my understanding it is not supported on DO.

I also tried with `transports: ['polling', 'websocket']` but I got `xhr poll error`.

What could be the issue?